# TrelloApp could not be instanciante in Angular JS (routeProvider)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, trello

I have this error

```
Failed to instantiate module trelloApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/unpr?p0=%24ro...
at Error (native)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:6:416
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:40:307
at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:38:308)
at Object.e [as invoke] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:39:64)
at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:37:279)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:37:403
at n (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:7:322)
at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:37:180)
at eb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js:40:435
```

And this error appear just after i've added this few line :

```
trelloApp.config(['$routeProvider',
 function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
 when('/board/:idBoard', {
   templateUrl: 'trello.php',
   controller: 'boardsController'
 }).
 when('/card/:idCard', {
   templateUrl: 'trello/views/cards.php',
   controller: 'cardsController'
 }).
 otherwise({
   redirectTo: 'trello.php'
 });
}]);
```

And i don't know why. I named correctly the controllers and templateUrl.

I have correctly declared my app :

```
var trelloApp = angular.module('trelloApp',[]);
```

I have see another way to create routeProvider without using the .config() , can it be the source of my problem ?

PS: i haven't forgot to contact https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular-route.js

Comment: if you'd use the non minified version of angular, the error message will be much clearer. Try that and see if the error makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

`$routeProvider` is a service in the `ngRoute` module.

You have to import this module into your app.

```
var trelloApp = angular.module('trelloApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

See the following example on the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example).